# Generate shell doesn't work on Windows Toolbox

Tags: webstorm

I enabled `Generate shell script` on Toolbox and I am sure have added the `C:\Windows` to path environment variables.

But it claims the `webstorm` is not a program, why?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the path that you used to export the generated shell scripts.

Ex.: If you set the path of the "Generate shell scripts" option to "C:/Shell Scripts" (without quotes of course); You need to add this path to your environment variables

[image: Generate shell scripts]

Answer (score 0):

What about changing your shell location to A custom path but not the system's path(e.g. c:\myshells)

then add your path to the system environment.

[image: Here is my working ground]

The "Select" function of my toolbox is not working, I need to fill the path on myself.